# Angular 16 - Firebase google auth login error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-oauth, angularfire

I'm trying to make a sign in / login with google only in angular 16 with firebase. When I click the "LogIn"  button, I get this error: "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GoogleAuthProvider')". I've done it this way because I couldn't find a way to get the authState to control whether an user is logged in or not with a simpler way. So if you either can provide a solution for this error or a way to make a working login with public guard(so a logged in user can't access the landing page) it'd be so helpful

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../models/user.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<User | null | undefined>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
          // Logged in
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          // Logged out
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    )
   }

   async googleSignin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
  }

  private updateUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

    const data = { 
      uid: user.uid, 
      email: user.email, 
      displayName: user.displayName, 
      photoURL: user.photoURL
    } 
  }

  async signOut() {
    await this.afAuth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

the problem is in this line: const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
it has something to do with the firebase import.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying using `new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()` which comes from `firebase/compat/app`.

Instead, try importing `GoogleAuthProvider` from `@firebase/auth`.

It should be like this

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from '@firebase/auth';

...

async googleSignin() {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider(); // Comes from '@firebase/auth'
    const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
}

...
```